# Permission denied error while executing shell command from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, shellexecute

I am trying to run shell command to open notepad from JavaScript. This is how my code looks like:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function runNotepad() {
        var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
        var commandtoRun = "C:\\WINDOWS\\Notepad.exe";
        oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun, null, "", "open", "1");
        }
 </script>
```

When i try to run this, it throws me an error saying `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Permission denied`.

I also have set `Allow active content to run in files on my computer` in `IE` but still no luck.

Any idea what am i missing here?

Comment: Curious, what is the intended purpose?  Knowing this might help a reader to suggest a suitable alternative, unless you are hellbent on using notepad.  For example, perhaps you would have a feature providing the user with text entry capabilities, which would be saved to, say, a database then later served up as a downloadable txt file to the user.

Comment: well, notepad was just for an example. my actual requirement is that i have start a windows application from browser which handles payment information.

Comment: This can't be done easily in my opinion, but you could probably fake it by providing a downloadable batch file that, when run, could then open the application.  Seems more trouble than its worth honestly.  Another option is to register an application protocol, the same way opening a .pdf file will generally open up acrobat.  More reading on protocol: [Registering an Application to a URL Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea what am i missing here?

No browser would allow JavaScript to arbitrarily start a process. This functionality is not available in Internet Explorer because of the security implications.

This will work if run from other Scripting Hosts, such as `cscript`, but not Internet Explorer.

Comment: is there any other way to start a windows app from asp.net on client system?

Comment: @Asdfg You could write a ClickOnce application that starts Notepad.exe.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run or create native objects inside webpage javascript.  The idea is that if someone could do that, then they could create a FileSystem object.  Then, while you idly browse their webpage, they play havoc with your file system.

If you need to do this, and have the file saved on the host's machine, save it as an HTML app (*.hta).